# Simplest free application for chaning recorded voice

Tags: sound, sound-editor

I would like to change sound of voice as if it was another person, make it nicer. Something not primitive, it should sounds good. Yet I'm looking for easiest way to do it.

Comment: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/my-voice-recording-file bs=1m count=1024` – There you go, voice recording changed!

Comment: @DavidFoerster .. funny. An ocerwrite don't change or chain - what ever op means. It just overwrite the file, right ?

Comment: @SorenA: It should change all recorded voices to silence (assuming standard PCM formats) and I think silence sounds perfect (not merely "good"). Maybe I should have pointed out more bluntly that OP didn't even give a superficial description of what they want which tends to result in terrible answers.

Comment: @DavidFoerster if it is clean now, then undo 'on hold' please.

Comment: @waltinator is it clear now ?

Answer (score 1):

Audacity is a good solution for editing sound.
https://www.audacityteam.org/

Is's available in the app catalog: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/audacity/

```
sudo apt-get install audacity
```